# Python scikit-learn SelectKBest words from sentences by speakers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use scikit-learn function SelectKBest on a database that contains sentences from two speakers. 
My goal is to find the 30 best words that can act as features to separate these two speakers, which I want to print to the screen.

The sentences are stored in a list `sentences[]` and I have the information as for who is the speaker for each of the sentences (stored in another list `speakers[]`)

I also need to create vectors for those K best features and be able to use classifiers on those vectors.

Current code: (sentences contains 10000 sentences for each speaker, sorted)

```py
speakers = [0] * 10000 + [1] * 10000
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)

kbest = SelectKBest(chi2, k=30).fit(vectors, speakers)
outcome = kbest.get_support()
for i in range(0,len(sentences)):
    if outcome[i]:
        print (sentences[i])
```

I'm not sure if it finds the correct words or selects whole sentences, and I'm not very sure how to print the words it finds if it does. (currently, it obviously prints whole sentences as I am printing directly a sentence that has a matching index to what SelectKBest found).

**I probably need to find the word in the i'th position of the feature vector, but I'm not sure how to do that.**

Comment: It would be better if your question contained a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you @HenriqueAndrade, I've added an example of my current code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. You are doing this:

```
outcome = kbest.get_support()
for i in range(0,len(sentences)):
    if outcome[i]:
        print (sentences[i])
```

`kbest.get_support()` will return a boolean array for the features of the data, not the sentences. But you are comparing (iterating) them over the sentences array, which don't make any sense.

`SelectKBest` will decide which features to keep or not based on the actual features passed into it. And those features are passed into it as form of words (not sentences) from the `TfidfVectorizer`.

Also, `SelectKBest` with `chi2` will only filter out (remove) those features that are found to be independent of the class. So remaining features have some impact on the classes. But to find out if that impact is positive or negative as you want (to find 30 best words that can act as features to separate these two speakers), this is not enough. For that you will need to have a classification model which can assign weights to those words (features) corresponding to the class.

See the example here for more details:

- https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/sklearn-text.html#baseline-model

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top k words given by `SelectKBest`

```
print([vectorizer.get_feature_names()[idx] for idx,flag in enumerate(outcome) if flag])
```